# ¿Cómo generar una region_id aleatoria pero que pertenezca a country_id y a su ves una city_id que le pertenezca a region_id?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo tres seeder que es País, Estado o región y cuidad ok,

En la table de users tengo la relación de country_id, region_id y de city_id, en mi UserFactory el campo es así country_id = Country::all()->random()->id se guarda un id aleatorio, pero si hago lo siguiente:

```
return $this->afterMaking(function (User $user) {
        $country = Country::find($user->country_id);
        $user->region_id = $country->id;
        $user->save();
    });
```

Si utilizo afterMaking donde es $user->region_id = $country->id; se guarda si el id es igual al id del country->id,

¿Cómo generar una region_id aleatoria pero que pertenezca a country_id?

Ya que si utilizo random()->id, se guardan region_id aleatorias quedan así por ejemplo: Nueva York Argentina, España Rusia etc.

Comment: ¿Deseas que `region_id` contenga todas las regiones de `country_id`? ¿En un arreglo? ¿Separadas por comas? O ¿Deseas que se genere una `region_id` aleatoria pero que pertenezca a `country_id`? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega un poco más de información de lo que deseas lograr.

Comment: Busco esto que se genere una region_id aleatoria pero que pertenezca a country_id

Comment: Y en tu tabla de regiones tienes algo que relacione la región con un determinado país? O de qué forma tu tabla de regiones sabe a qué país pertenece?

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré fue la siguiente. Para obtener primero un country_id en UserFactory.php puse lo siguiente:

```
'country_id' => Country::all()->random()->id,
```

Utilizando los callback de las factory de laravel afterMaking, para obtener una region_id que pertenezca a la relación country_id puse lo siguiente:

```
public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterMaking(function (User $user) {
        $user->region_id = Country::findOrFail($user->country_id)->regions()->first()->id;
    });
}
```

Y finalmente para obtener una cuidad que pertenezca a la region_id fue algo similar:

```
$user->city_id = Region::find($user->region_id)
        ->cities()
        ->first()->id;
```

Todo dentro del mismo afterMaking, solamente que en el archivo DatabaseSeeder.php, se coloca make de la siguiente manera:

```
User::factory(5)->make();
```

Tarde algunos días en lograrlo.